# How to get parent button from ButtonStyle without using id?

Tags: qt, qml

I created a component (SidebarMenuButton) that is used in the main qml file multiple times. The button has styles that should be inherited by all it's 'instances'. Here is the SidebarMenuButton.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

Button {
    width: buttonNewMessage.width
    height: buttonNewMessage.height
    anchors {
        horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        topMargin: 5
    }
    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            color: 'transparent'
        }
        label: Text {
            text: parent.text // undefined here
            color: 'white'
            font.family: 'Helvetica'
            font.pixelSize: 12
            font.bold: true
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
    }
}
```

And a part of my main qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2    

Window {
    id: main
    title: 'Messenger'
    width: 1024
    height: 768
    minimumWidth: 800
    minimumHeight: 600

    RowLayout {
        id: layout
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 0

        Rectangle {
            id: sidebar
            color: '#3C3E55'
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 200

            ButtonCompanyName {
                id: buttonCompanyName
            }

            ButtonNewMessage {
                id: buttonNewMessage
            }

            SidebarMenuButton {
                id: buttonInbox
                text: 'Inbox (1)'
                anchors.top: buttonNewMessage.bottom
            }

            SidebarMenuButton {
                id: buttonSentMessages
                text: 'Sent messages'
                anchors.top: buttonInbox.bottom
            }

            SidebarMenuButton {
                id: buttonStarred
                text: 'Starred'
                anchors.top: buttonSentMessages.bottom
            }
        }
```

I commented the line with error. parent there doesn't refer to button so the text in all buttons is empty. I need to access parent button from there and get it's text property. The component has no id cause it's used multiple times and ids are assigned in the main qml file. So the question is: how can I get that button text without id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to set text in your case.

1)The Button for which you are applying the style is available as `control` property in `ButtonStyle` class. You can set the the text as `text:control.text`

[Reference:control property(ButtonStyle)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-buttonstyle.html#control-prop)

2)You can give an id to the `Button` in `SidebarMenuButton` type and access its `text`property.

```
Button
{
    id:button
    .
    .
    .
    text: button.text   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an `id` inside your component file that would not conflict with the id you use when you instantiate the component somewhere else. I use the same value for the id of most of my QML components: `container` so that I can easily reference properties from the root of the item.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

Button {
    id: container
    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            color: 'transparent'
        }
        label: Text {
            text: container.text
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you instantiate this component in another file you set whichever id you want and it would still work